# android interface make callback function optional

Tags: android, interface, callback

I have a simple class with an interface enabled and works proper when used.

```
interface interfacename{
   void function1();
   void function2();
}


public class asyncfunction(){
   public interfacename listener;
   ...
   onasyncStart( ... ){
        listener.function1();
   }
   ...
   ...
   onasyncComplete( ... ){
        listener.function2();
   }
}

public myclass(){
   ....
   ....
   methodcall(new interfacename(){
       @Override
       public void function1(){
          // executes proper
       }

       @Override
       public void function2(){
          // executes proper
       }
   }
}
```

So the above method works proper.

But i want to call only the function1() sometimes and only function2() when needed.

I don't want both methods to be implemented always. The code looks big and im not sure if it slows down code or not ( not on the milli second level btw ) but it would be really nice if there was another way to have the option to execute particular call backs when needed.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're really looking at splitting up your `interface` into multiple interfaces, and change the method that accepts this `interface` as a parameter, so that it will instead accept the `interface` that it requires (e.g. `InterfaceOne`) in order to call a method in that `interface` (e.g. `function1()`). Another method might want to call `function2()`, in which case it will accept an argument of type `InterfaceTwo`.

If however you need to always call both methods of the `interface` in your method, but you don't always need to call any code in the methods of that `interface`, what you're looking at instead is the following.

Instead of creating a new anonymous class of type `interfacename`, you could use a base class with empty method bodies, and simply override the ones you need. Methods implemented by the abstract base class are essentially optional, while those that are not implemented are required methods.

This is a very common pattern in Java development.

```
public interface InterfaceName {

    void function1();
    void function2();

}

public abstract class BaseInterfaceName implements InterfaceName {

    public void function1() {
    }

    public void function2() {
    }

}

public class MyClass {

    public void myMethod() {
        myMethodWithInterface(new BaseInterfaceName() {
            @Override
            public void function2() {
                System.out.println("function2");
            }
        })
    }

    public void myMethodWithInterface(InterfaceName intf) {
        intf.function1();
        intf.function2();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution is the one explained by @Nicklas.

But, if you use Java 8, you can use the `default method`. So you can declare your interface in this way:

```
public interface InterfaceName {
    default void function1(){ /* do nothing */}
    default void function2(){ /* do nothing */}
}
```

So, you can avoid implementing the methods, since you are providing a default implementation. In my example the default is to do nothing, but of course, you can personalize them.

Comment: Since im using android studio, is that dependent on the java version installed on system or has a package of its own ?

Comment: Java 8 is great! Sadly this question is tagged with Android, which doesn't support Java 8 features yet.

Comment: It depens on your used SDK Java version. So if you use Android, I suppose you are using JDK 7.

Comment: @user1217974 Android supports Java 7 language features, but not Java 8. Some features can be implemented through 3rd party tools, but I don't believe this particular feature has been back-ported.

Comment: I know @user1217974 I said only that in Java you can do it, since it really seems a Java generic question.

Comment: ah i c .... found many answers from stackoverflow. Sad that something like a default do nothing feature for interface would really help me... i have enough callbacks lol. Is something like this possible via a abstract method ?

Comment: @user1217974 Check my answer for the Java 7 / Android implementation of this pattern, specifically the class `BaseInterfaceName`.

Comment: Yes it does! It does now anyway. @GVillani82 can you update your answer?